# ggplot. create a loop to plot a box plot different column in a df

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello this is my first time here and I am very new to R programming.
I am looking at the how concentration of metabolite changes overtime for beef. I wrote a ggplot code to plot them which I am happy about but I want to repeat them for all the metabolites(in different column). Is there a code to repeat all of this or do I need to just copy/paste the code.
Thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYfaw.png)

Comment: Please make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Don’t add data/code as images. Provide a reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will do better next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to gather/pivot_longer your dataset using tidyr
And then use ggplot with facet_wrap on all metabolities.
Here't the working example with mtcars

```
library(tidyverse)
df = mtcars
print(df)
df %>% 
pivot_longer(mpg:gear,names_to="metric",values_to="val") %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(carb),y=val)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~metric, ncol = 3)
```

For your case, it should be something like

```
df %>%
pivot_longer(isoleucine:carnitine,names_to="metabolites",values_to="amount") %>%
ggplot(aes(x=factor(Day),y=amount)) + 
geom_boxplot() + 
facet_wrap(~metabolites, ncol = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the facet graph looks awesome to show each metabolites with changes in time. This is a life saver !!

Just another question of interest is there a way to loop the code and get individual plot of each metabolites and export them out as picture file ?

Comment: i would use loop in this case.
df_long = df %>%
pivot_longer(isoleucine:carnitine,names_to="metabolites",values_to="amount")
##new line
list_metabolities = unique(df_long$metaboloties)
##newline
for (x in list_metabolities){
  df_long %>% filter(metabolities==x) %>% ggplot(aes(x=factor(Day),y=amount)) + geom_boxplot()
ggsave(paste0(x,".png"))
}

I never use ggsave before, but i think it should works